# how to hide datatable rows where code is have "." e.g 1.1, 1.2 through jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, web

I take data of two inputs to another page through ajax. I used these two values in the query and shown the result of the select query in a data table which is return back to success function and shown in the table on the main page.

After that, I want to use a condition that data with `"."` `(accounting->subaccounts)` hide unless He clicks a button.

I just need an idea to hide it I can do more. let me show you my code.

This is the button:

```
<input type="button" id="generate" onclick="getData();" value="Generate"  
class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" />
```

The div where i shown the table:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12" id="tab"></div>
```

the ajax function:

```
function getData() {
            var date = $("#date").val();
            var classId = $("#class").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/getTrailBalanceData.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "date": date,
                    "classId": classId,
                },
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
        //alert(data);                  
                    $("#tab").html(data);

                    var row_main_code = $("#main_code").val();


                    if (row_main_code.indexOf(".") > -1) {
    //                  $("#tbl_row").addClass("hide");
                    } else {
  //                      $("#tbl_row").removeClass("hide");
 //                    $("#main_code").parents("tr").hide();
 //                    $("#tbl_row").addClass("hide");
      //                 $("#main_code").val("hide");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

The `if(rowmaincode.indexof('.')>-1)` condition in "success" I tried but not give desirable result I am confused I don't know why but let me show you the other page code:

```
<table id="trail_balance_list" class="table table-bordered table-condensed bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive">
<thead id="table_head">
    <tr class="bg-success">

        <th class=" text-center">Code</th>
        <th class=" text-center">Account Title</th>
        <th class=" text-center" >Debit</th>
        <th class=" text-center" >Credit</th>
        <th class=" text-center" >Action</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
    <tr  id="tbl_row" class="">
            <td><?php echo $row['main_code']; ?><input type="hidden" id="main_code" value="<?php echo $row['main_code']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['account_title']; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="hidden" id="total_credit_input" name="total_credit" value="0" /></th>
        <th><input type="hidden" id="total_debit_input" name="total_debit" value="0" /></th>
        <td class="bg-warning text-center" id="total_debit">0.00</td>
        <td class="bg-warning text-center" id="total_credit" >0.00</td>

    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#trail_balance_list").dataTable();
   });
</script>
```

the result I get is like : (see image), I want to show only like 1,2,3,4

[image: i want show only like 1,2,3,4]

Comment: Please post your query. Do you need to hide just the column code or entire row

Comment: $query = "SELECT `main_code`,`account_title` FROM `data` WHERE `main_code`;"; thats the query and i want to hide entire row @Sinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implement a similar idea in your code, hope you can do that. I have added a sample below.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#act_button', function() {
  $('#trail_balance_list > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:first').text().indexOf('.') >= 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="act_button">hide decimal rows</button>
<table id="trail_balance_list" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>33.3</td>
      <td>444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>555</td>
      <td>666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>77</td>
      <td>666</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to hide it such a way that i am able to show it back when click on button but while loop will totally ignore those values. In short i want condition in main Page  success function and i want the solution to be client side

Comment: please check the above answer, its a sample for you.

Comment: now this was helpful. well thanks i use your idea to do it without click event and bla bla